# Python Pandas - How to aggregate horizontally grouping by some levels of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A1','B1'):range(0,5),
                   ('A1','B2'):range(1,6),
                   ('A2','B1'):range(2,7),
                   ('A2','B2'):range(3,8),})



    A1      A2
    B1  B2  B1  B2
    0   1   2   3
    1   2   3   4
    2   3   4   5
    3   4   5   6
    4   5   6   7
```

How can I groupby the first level of the columns and sum up values across columns on each row and in each group, and generate:

```
    A1  A2
    1   5
    3   7
    5   9
    7   11
    9   13
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the `axis=1` to `groupby()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()

Out[]:
   A1  A2
0   1   5
1   3   7
2   5   9
3   7  11
4   9  13
```

Comment: Also, `df.sum(axis=1,level=0)`

Comment: The duplicate that @Wen linked covers both answers.